# Okhttp post return null

Tags: java, android, json, post, okhttp

I printed the json in execution I copied it I try the same json and url in postman and it's working so I don't think the problem is with url or json . rs variable in main is always null

```
public class PostLocation {

public static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8");

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

public String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {

    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(json, JSON);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(body)
            .build();


    Response response = null;
    try {

        response = client.newCall(request).execute();  return response.body().string();
    } finally {
        if (response != null) { response.close(); }
    }

}

String bowlingJson(Double lg,Double lt) {
    return "{\"id\": null,\"datetime\": \"2019-01-10T19:00:00.000+0000\",\"user\": {\"id\": 1 },\"latitude\": "+lt+",\"longitude\": "+lg+"}";
}
```

}

main :

```
            String rs = null;
            String json = null;
            //post
            try{
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

                PostLocation pl = new PostLocation();
                json = pl.bowlingJson(location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
                System.out.println(json);
                rs = pl.post("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/locations", json);
            }catch (IOException EX){
            }finally {
                t.setText("\n " + location.getLongitude() + " " + location.getLatitude() );
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was java.net.ConnectException :
I changed localhost(127.0.0.1) with 10.0.2.2 because Android emulator runs in a Virtual Machine

then I had a problem java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout 
I added :

```
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    builder.connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // connect timeout
            .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // write timeout
            .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES); // read timeout

    client = builder.build();
```

Now it's working

Answer (score 0):

This is your formatted Json:

```
{ 
 "id":null,
 "datetime":"2019-01-10T19:00:00.000+0000",
 "user":{ 
  "id":1
 },
 "latitude":"+lt+",
 "longitude":"+lg+"
}
```

This looks to me that `lt` and `lg` will always have +'s around them.

Why don't you use `String.format` for example:

```
String.format("{\"id\": null,\"datetime\": \"2019-01-10T19:00:00.000+0000\",\"user\": {\"id\": 1 },\"latitude\": %f,\"longitude\": %f}", lt, lg);
```

Comment: I try it but the same problem, and like I said the problem is not in json String or url because I print the returned String when I execute the app and I make the same json and the same url in postman and it's working